# preg_match with in different tags

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm in need of some assistance. I'm trying to scrape some specify data from a website.

```
<tbody>
    <tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 1;">
        <td style="width: 184.4pt; border: none; border-left: solid windowtext 1.5pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;" valign="top" width="307">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">Certifikat springer 1000m</p>
        </td>

        <td style="width: 44.7pt; border: none; border-right: solid windowtext 1.5pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;" valign="top" width="75">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: right; line-height: normal;" align="right">90,-</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 2;">
        <td style="width: 184.4pt; border: none; border-left: solid windowtext 1.5pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;" valign="top" width="307">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">Certifikat springer 1200m</p>
        </td>

        <td style="width: 44.7pt; border: none; border-right: solid windowtext 1.5pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;" valign="top" width="75">
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: right; line-height: normal;" align="right">100,-</p>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

what I want is to get the "Certifikat springer 1000" from mos-yfti-irow1 and the 90,- from the next TD. but I don't want to get the data from mos-yfti-irow2 in this output.

I'm want to build something where people can compare prices on some activities on our sports group with different clubs. I'm not really sure how to.

This is what I have for now, but can't really get it to work

```
    <?php 

    $file_string = file_get_contents('http://www.mfkviborg.dk/index.php?    option=com_content&view=article&id=21&Itemid=151');

    preg_match_all('/<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt;(.*)">(.*)<\/p>/i', $file_string, $links);

    ?>

    <p><strong>Links:</strong> <em>(Name - Link)</em><br />
    <?php
    echo '<ol>';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($links[1]); $i++) {
        echo '<li>' . $links[2][$i] . ' - ' . $links[1][$i] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    ?>
</p>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is really hard. I'll eventually kind of work if you're presistent but the resulting code will typically be impossible to understand and maintain. Unless it's an existing legacy project where you have no choice or you actually enjoy the endeavour, I suggest you try a proper HTML parser. See: [Document Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- The `.` does not match with newlines, unless you specify the `s` modifier at the end of your regex. So that should be added.
- The `.*` is greedy, so it will match as much as possible including some intermediate `</p>`. It should not do that, so add a `?` (in both cases)

Less of a problem, but still worth changing:

- The first capture group probably does not give you useful information, so remove the parentheses there.
- The `.` in `.0001` is taken as any character, so you should escape it. One way is to put it as `[.]`

This gives you this line of code:

```
preg_match_all('/<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: [.]0001pt;.*?">(.*?)<\/p>/is', 
             $file_string, $links);
```

#### Use DOM parser

Note that if your source HTML only changes slightly (with extra spacing or changing double to single quotes, or swaps the position of attributes ...) you will bump into issues, and be called to adapt the code.

It is much better to use the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) interface together with a [DOMXPath query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php). Here is how that could work:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($file_string, LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR );
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//p[contains(@class, 'MsoNormal') and contains(@style, 'margin-bottom: .0001pt')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Instead of the `loadHTML` method you can also use the `load` method, and pass the URL as first argument.

#### Follow-up

You asked in comments to further filter the output by `tr` with `mso-yfti-irow` in the `style` attribute:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//tr[contains(@style, 'mso-yfti-irow')]//p[contains(@class, 'MsoNormal') and contains(@style, 'margin-bottom: .0001pt')]");
```

Comment: Thanks trincot

one more question, so now, im getting the data, but the problem is, that i only need the price (eg. the 90) from the tr mso-yfti-irow: 1 and not from the rest 9 tr's. so i need the script only to handle the data from tr mso-yfti-irow: 1. but still doing the same as it does now. how i that posible . ?

Comment: See addition to my answer. If you have further questions, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, use a decent parser instead, e.g. `DOMDocument()`:

```
<?php
# set up the dom
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_data_here, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);# | LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_NOENT );

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//tr[contains(@style, 'mso-yfti-irow: 1')]") as $row) {
    $text = $xpath->query("td/p/text()", $row);
    $certificate = $text[0]->nodeValue;
    $price = $text[1]->nodeValue;
    echo "$certificate | $price\n";
}
?>
```

This yields for your example string:

```
Certifikat springer 1000m | 90,-
```

The code snippet sets up the `DOM` and queries it with an `xpath` expression afterwards, see the documentation on [**`PHP.net`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).